# AnyObject is not convertible to UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode

I'm using the Beginning Swift Programming book by AppCoda and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this block of code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

var restaurantNames = ["Cafe Deadend", "Homei", "Teakha", "CafeLoisl", "Petite Oyster", "For Kee Restaurant", "Po's Atelier", "Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh’s Chocolate", "Palomino Espresso", "Upstate", "Traif", "Graham Avenue Meats And Deli", "Waffle & Wolf", "Five Leaves", "Cafe Lore", "Confessional", "Barrafina", "Donostia", "Royal Oak", "CASK Pub and Kitchen"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return restaurantNames.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
        UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}

}
```

This line is throw a 'AnyObject is not convertible to 'UITableViewCell'

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

I'm really new to Swift and iOS programming in general so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i can give you a swift sample code which i have used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `as` to `as!`

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

Also make sure that you have added a prototype cell to your storyboard with the reusable string name `"Cell"`

Answer (score 2):

```
//MARK: Tableview
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return tabledata.count


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = tabledata[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I have used this code for tableview....You can change this according to your need.Even I'm new in swift or else I would've correct your code.